# SQL query to get unique rows of IDs that depend of another column of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, database-design

I'm even having trouble putting this into words. I have a table with fields 
`userID, fName, lName, reportsTo, officeID` and another one with `officeID`.

I need to `join` these two tables and then get the `distinct`values of `userIDs` where other users `reportsTo = userID.`

I don't really have a problem joining the tables, so for the sake of simplicity I'll illustrate what I need:

```
userID fName lName reportsTo
1      anna  foo   null
2      john  bar   1
3      mary  quux  2
4      paul  faa   2
5      dan   ber   4
```

I need a query that will give me:

```
1 anna foo null
2 john bar 1
4 paul faa 2
```

since those are the members that have at least 1 person under them.
Thank you very much

Comment: Provide a fiddle with some sample data, and desired result for this data.

Comment: *get the distinct values of userIDs* DISTINCT is applicable to absolute copies. If any difference present you must specify the criteria which allows to select one record from a lot of records which are a group by its partial value.

Answer (score 0):

You can alias tables and treat your one table like it is 2:

`select T1.* from mytable T1 INNER JOIN mytable T2 ON T1.userID = T2.reportsTo`

You can provide an actual fiddle and get a working answer, but if you alias your tables they are like 'copies' and can be used independently of each-other.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use subquery:

```
select * 
from test
where userID in (select reportsTo from test);
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c63f49052411a225e9d3a34264a1d104)

**RESULT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this with a `subquery`

```
SELECT * from yourtable 
WHERE userID IN (SELECT DISTINCT reportsTo FROM yourtable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on the role that `officeid` plays here, but the following query should return only users where at least one user reports to them;

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM my_table t
   JOIN my_table t1 ON t1.reportsto = t.userid
```